# How is lazy evaluation working in this example?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

If I have this function:
`let x = print_endline "foo" in x,x;;`
it has this signature: `unit * unit = ((), ())` 
and evaluates to `foo`

I dont understand why it prints foo once.

On the other hand: `let x () = print_endline "foo" in x(),x();;`  will print foo twice and has the signature:
`unit * unit = ((), ())`

can someone explain the principle behind this and how it works in this specific example?

Comment: You are describing an [evaluation strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy) dubbed **call by name**, where variables contain unevaluated expressions, that are computed each time the variable is requested. This is different from **call by need (lazy evaluation)** in which variables contain expressions but these expressions are computed at most once, when needed. OCaml follows yet another strategy, dubbed **call by value (eager evaluation)**, in which expressions are evaluated eagerly and, consequently, variables contain just values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OCaml is an eager language unless directed otherwise. To create lazy values we use the `lazy` keyword, e.g., `lazy (print_endline "foo")` will create a lazy value of type `unit Lazy.t` that will print `foo`, once it is forced with `Lazy.force`.

All other values in OCaml are eager and are evaluated immediately. You got confused with the `let .. in ...` syntactic form.

The syntactic form

```
let <var> = <expr1> in <expr2>
```

first evaluates `<expr1>` and then evaluates `<expr2>` with the value of `<expr1>` bound to `<var>`. Finally, the result of `<expr2>` becomes the value of the whole form.

So when you say, `let x = 2 in x + x` you first evaluate `2` and bind it to `x` and then evaluate `x + x` with `x=2`, which is `4`, so the value of the expression `let x = 2 in x + x` in `4`. This is a pure expression, it doesn't define any functions and doesn't bind `x` in the global context.

Going back to your example,

```
let x = print_endline "foo" in x, x
```

we first evaluate `<expr1>`, which is `print_endline "foo"` that has the side effect of printing `foo` and returns the value `()` of type `unit`. Next, `()` is bound to `x` and the `<expr2>` is evaluated, which `x,x`, and which is equal to `(),()`.

Your second example,

```
let x () = print_endline "foo" in x (), x ()
```

binds `x` to the function `fun () -> print_endline "foo"` since

```
let f x = <expr>
```

is the syntactic sugar for

```
let f = fun x -> <expr>
```

i.e., to a definition of a function.

Therefore, your expression first evaluates `<expr1>`, which is now `fun () -> print_endline "foo"` and binds it to `x`. Now you evaluate `x (), x ()` and calls `x ()` twice, both calls return `()`.

Finally, you said in your question that,

> If I have this function: let x = print_endline "foo" in x,x;;

You don't have any functions there. Much like in `let x = 2 in x + x`, you are not defining any functions but just evaluate `x+x` with `x` bound to `2`.  After it is evaluated, there are no leftovers, `x` is not bound to anything. In C-like syntax, it is the same as

```
{
   int x = 2;
   x + x;
}
```

So if you want to define a function, you have to use the syntax

```
let <name> <params> = 
   <expr>
```

Where `<expr>` is the body of the function that is evaluated in a context where each parameter is substituted with its actual value (argument).

E.g.,

```
let print_foo () = 
  print_endline "foo"
```

or,

```
let sum_twice x y = 
  let z = x + y in
  2 * z
```

I would suggest reading the [OCaml Tutorial](https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/coreexamples.html) to get a better idea of OCaml syntax.

Answer (score 2):

There is no lazy evaluation involved in this code at all. It would be more the other way around: lazy code (in OCaml) often involves having a function of the form `() -> 'a` instead of a value `'a`, but this doesn't mean that *any* function of this form has to do with lazy evaluation.

In the first snippet, `let x = print_endline "foo" in x, x`, you are binding `x` to a value, the result of `print_endline "foo"`, and then returning `x, x`. However, by doing so you must call `print_endline "foo"`, which will print `foo`. At this point, `x : unit = ()`. Then, you return `x, x`, that is, `(), ()`.

In the second snippet, `let x () = print_endline "foo" in x (), x ()`, you are defining a function `x`. That form is syntax sugar for `let x = fun () -> print_endline "foo" in x (), x ()`. For this reason, before the evaluation of `x (), x ()`, you have `x : unit -> unit = <fun>`. Then, you call that function twice, each time printing `foo`, and returning `()`.

Note that, when you write something like `let x () = ...`, you could also be writing `let x (y: unit) = ...`, except that since the type `unit` has a single constructor (`()`), OCaml allows you to deconstruct it directly in the function declaration. Which is why you are allowed to write `let x () = ...`.

Comment: I find this syntax unnecessarily confusing.

Comment: @stht55 Which syntax?

Comment: Note: `let x = fun a b ->` is syntactic sugar for `let x = function a -> function b ->`. The rabbit hole of syntactic sugar is deep.

Comment: lazy code in OCaml is created with the `lazy` keyword and doesn't involve having a function of the form `unit -> _`. A function is just a function and no laziness is involved in its definition or evaluation.

Comment: @ivg Hum, the `Seq` module implements lazy sequences through `'a Seq.t` which is a `unit -> 'a Seq.node` function, isn't it?

Comment: No, it is a confusing jargon to name it lazy. In fact, it is a delayed list, just a thunk, which doesn't involve any lazy compuations. Read here about the laziness https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Lazy.html

Comment: Agreed with @ivg. *Laziness* is the conjunction of two things: (1) delaying a computation (2) memoizing its result. By simply wrapping a computation under a closure `fun () -> …` you delay, but you don’t memoize. There is no guarantee that a given Seq element will be computed only once.

Comment: @Maëlan I have the impression the fact that laziness implies memoization is not really standard. I have searched for either of the definitions in the past few days, and found nothing really probing. In my CS classes, IIRC lazy would refer only to deferred evaluation, often coupled with memoization (but not implied). Do you have any source mentioning laziness forcefully implies memoization? On the other hand, I tried some lazy languages and they do memoize, so maybe I just recalled wrongly.

Comment: @BlackBeans I don’t know then, perhaps literature disagrees on terminology? I always thought of laziness as implying non-repetition of evaluation (otherwise I’d just call it call-by-name). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) (see 1st sentence) has references that appear to support this. [Also, tangentially, it may be possible that a share of the literature only uses the term _memoization_ with the meaning of remembering a function’s output (e.g. with a lookup table), which is slightly different thing.]

Comment: @Maëlan yeah I read that page but literally in the second paragraph they say "lazy evaluation is often combined with memoization". However, it is true that, as you said, in that case memoization may mean function memoization, in which case it makes sense.